# How to simulate the 1-D motion of a particle under constant acceleration?

Tags: dynamic, physics, simulation, scheduling

I am trying to represent the position of an object under freefall, but am completely lost.
Here is my attempt so far:

```
time = 0;
increment = 10;
distance := 0 - time*(time*increment); 

{Dynamic[Refresh[{time++ 1, ClockGauge[DateList[]]}, UpdateInterval -> 1]],
 Dynamic @ distance, 
 Dynamic @ Framed[Graphics[Disk[{0, distance}, 10], 
                           PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {1, -1000}}]]}
```

Which results in:

> [image]

The bar on the left should represent the position of the object under freefall, and the number to the right of the bar should represent its *y* coordinate. **However this clearly accelerates way too fast way too soon**.

Basically the main problem here is that I don't know how to translate the '10m per second per second' into a language that *Mathematica* can understand. Could someone help me with what formula to use?

Answer (score 3):

I would build your simulation with a [`DynamicModule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DynamicModule.html) showing a table made with a [`Grid`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Grid.html) and controlled by a [`Trigger`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Trigger.html). First I would define a function that calculates distance when given time and acceleration.

```
dist[a_, t_] := a t^2/2
```

Next I would get the basic functionality right. A grid showing time and distance with a trigger to control it.

```
With[{a = -9.8, dmax = -1000.},
  With[{tmax = Sqrt[2. dmax/a]},
    DynamicModule[{t = 0., d = 0.},
      Grid[{
        {Dynamic @ t, Dynamic[d = dist[a, t]]},
        {Trigger[Dynamic @ t, {0., tmax, 1}, 1], SpanFromLeft}
      }]
    ]]]
```

[image: step1]

Only after the basic stuff was debugged, would I add the fancy stuff -- headers and gauges.

```
With[{a = -9.8, dmax = -1000.},
  With[{tmax = Sqrt[2. dmax/a]},
    DynamicModule[{t = 0., d = 0.},
      Grid[{
        {Style["Time", "SB"], Style["Distance", "SB"]},
        {Dynamic@t, Dynamic[d = dist[a, t]]},
        {AngularGauge[Dynamic @ t, {0, Ceiling @ tmax}, ScaleDivisions -> {3, 5}], 
         VerticalGauge[Dynamic @ d, {0, dmax}]},
        {Trigger[Dynamic @ t, {0., tmax, .1}, 1.], SpanFromLeft}
      }, Frame -> All]
    ]]]
```

[image: step2]

The above implements no more than the basics of what you asked for. There is no end or refinement that could be done to make it prettier. Nevertheless, I think it provides a good example of how *Mathematica* provides us all the tools needed to write simple physics simulations in very few lines of code.